# Как сохранить в переменные введенные два числа(арабские или римские) и по середине операцию(+, -, *, /)?

Tags: java

ввожу два числа, например, так: 1 + 2 (с пробелами)

сохранение затем в num1, operation, num2(Как это сделать?)

и вариант с римскими:
VI - III

и те и другие числа принадлежат массиву от 1 до 10 и от I до X соответственно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод split для разделения строкИ на стрОки, между которыми стояла строкА, переданная в кач-ве аргумента

```
    int firstNumber, secondNumber;
    String operation; 
    String numOperationNum = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");
    if(numOperationNum.length != 3){
        System.out.println("Неверный формат ввода");
    } else {
        firstNumber =  Integer.parseInt(numOperationNum[0]);
        operation = numOperationNum[1];
        secondNumber =  Integer.parseInt(numOperationNum[2]);

        // если же нужно парсить римские цифры от 1 до 10(хранятся в массиве m длиной 11)
        boolean firstStated, secondStated;
        for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
            if(numOperationNum[0].equals(m[i])){
                firstNumber = i + 1;
                firstStated = true;
            }
            if(numOperationNum[2].equals(m[i])){
                secondNumber = i + 1;
                secondStated = true;
            }
        }
        if(!firstStated || !secondStated){
            //error
        }
    }
```

Comment: спсасибо, а как спарсить римские цифры?

Comment: А для этого ищите парсер римских цифр, это отдельная задача. Причем задача интересная, постараюсь сейчас написать.

Comment: а может упростить задачу то, что всего 2 из 10 цифр надо спарсить, от I до X

Comment: да, это серьезно упростит задачу. Я то пошел полноценный парсер писать. Обновил ответ

Comment: а можно как то такой парсер использовать для выражения I + X, просто хотелось чтобы все части сохранились в отдельные переменные

Comment: Я не понял вопроса. Это выражение должно нормально обрабатываться, в firstNumber запишется 1, в operation +, в secondNumber 10.

Comment: у меня калькулятор, он может принимать только арабские или только римские цифры, вводятся они с консоли в двух разных программах

Comment: Как это в двух разных программах? По сети переменными обмениваются? В чем проблема то?

Comment: другими словами, я два раза запускаю программу, первый раз прочитать арабские цифры и знак и сохранить в переменные, во второй раз римские со знаком и тоже в переменные

Comment: что вводится арабская или римская цифра, как раз программа должна проверить

Comment: Ага, значит вам просто нужно добавить проверку - является ли элемент числом, и является ли элемент римской цифрой. Если не является ни тем, ни тем, значит нужно выбросить ошибку. В тело первого if'а суете парсер числа, в тело второго - парсер римской цифры.